# How to ban a specific IP from my website?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ip

I'm using Apache,hosted on Linux.

Answer (score 3):

`/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -s A.B.C.D -j DROP`

Comment: Will it still work after reboot?

Comment: @PHP: nope, you'll need to add the command to an `/etc/rc.local` or `/etc/rc.firewall` script to make sure it's run on reboot (and/or firewall restart).

Comment: No, you will have to add a script thats run on boot up

Answer (score 3):

womble's answer will block these users from even sending requests tou your server. If you want them to see the `403 Access Denied` Apache error page, put this in `.htaccess` file:

```
order allow,deny
deny from 192.168.44.201
allow from all
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is it will only fix a single vhost/site.  Using womble's solution is server-wide and much more efficient.

Comment: @Keiran: they're very different solutions; if you're using multiple vhosts, obviously you'd need to include this multiple places.  the solution stands tho: if you want the IP to see an Apache error, you need to block it in Apache.  if you don't want traffic from the IP going anywhere, the iptables solution is appropriate.

Comment: This solution is good and will work even if you have several vhosts. Just put it in the global configuration file, not in a .htaccess.